# Load Canvas image into Excel

Tags: java, image, canvas, apache-poi, javafx-8

I created a plot on [`Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/canvas/Canvas.html). Now I want to add the image to an Excel file.

I know how to get a [`WritableImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/WritableImage.html) from `Canvas` and I know that I need an `InputStream` to write an image in Excel with [`addPicture()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#addPicture(java.io.InputStream,%20int)). The problem is how to link these two.

I could save this image to file and then open and load it to Excel, but maybe there is a way to avoid this?

Comment: instead of writing to a file via ImageIO.write() you can also write to ByteArrayOutputStream. Next you can add the picture via addPicture(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes of the ByteArrayOutputStream)) to the workbook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `PipedInputStream`/`PipedOutputStream` to accomplish this:

```
Image image = ...
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);

PipedOutputStream pos;
try (PipedInputStream pis = new PipedInputStream()) {
    pos = new PipedOutputStream(pis);
    new Thread(() -> {
        try {
            ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", pos);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
    }).start();
    workbook.addPicture(pis, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
```

or you could write the data to a array using `ByteArrayOutputStream`:

```
Image image = ...
BufferedImage bImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write(bImage, "png", bos);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
}
workbook.addPicture(bos.toByteArray(), Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
```